# What's the difference between data products and intelligent systems?

Tags: tools, education, definitions

Basically, both are software systems that are based on data and algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very vague question. However, I will try to make sense of it. Considering rules of *logic* as well as your statement that both *entities* are "software systems that are based on data and algorithms", it appears that **data products** are *intelligent systems* and **intelligent systems** are, to some degree, *data products*. Therefore, it can be argued that the difference between the terms "data products" and "intelligent systems" is purely in the **focus** (*source* of information or *purpose* of system dimensions) of each type of systems (*data* **vs.** *intelligence/algorithms*).